# Access itftennis.com player acceptance list with Api access

Tags: javascript, api

I want to access the Player Acceptance listing using API but i have not been able to find any API library for this so that i can access it using javascript

One [this page](https://www.itftennis.com/en/tournament/w60-rio-de-janeiro/bra/2022/w-itf-bra-09a-2022/acceptance-list/) i noticed that it accesses player list with following script

```
<script>
        var id = 'w-itf-bra-09a-2022';
        var circuitCode = 'WT';
        var tournamentCategory = 'W60';
        var filters = null;

        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(AcceptanceList, {
                tournamentKey: id,
                circuitCode: circuitCode,
                tournamentCode: tournamentCategory,
                filters: filters
            }),
            document.getElementById('acceptance-list-container')
        );
    </script>
```

I am not sure how it work as i can see its somehow making call and  filling the `acceptance-list-container` container with player details.

It seems its using react which i am not familiar can i somehow access same with javascript.

Comment: It is using React and the javascript is in `bundle.js`. Good luck understanding it though. Compiled React isn't designed for human consumption.

Comment: @Ouroborus, Thanks, so there is no easy way.. may be scrapping with some third party library may make it easier

Comment: You might look at the network traffic and see if anything useful is in there. It has to get the data from somewhere.

Comment: I was actually looking at that, just to see if there is any specific JS file but nothing which could relate to this.. May be web scrapping could be another way around.. as element container remains same at different levels of tournament `acceptance-list-container`

Comment: It wouldn't be a javascript file. It would likely be in JSON and doesn't need to be named in any particular way. Probably [this one](https://www.itftennis.com/tennis/api/TournamentApi/GetAcceptanceList?tournamentKey=w-itf-bra-09a-2022&circuitCode=WT).

Comment: If its like then it can be consumed it is in good json format.. even though it will take lot of effort to get it right for a person like me who does occasional programing